# How to set one or more days to repeat the alarm weekly in alarm manager for flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-alarms

I want to create a weekly alarm which repeat periodically in given days. I try to use [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager) for this task. Using this, I could create a periodic alarm by giving a specific date to start and a duration of 7 days.

```
void _createPeriodicAlarm() async {
    final _id = Random().nextInt(pow(2, 31));
    await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(const Duration(days: 7), _id, _printHello, startAt: DateTime(2020, 8, 1)); }
```

But what I want is, let user to pick one or more days to repeat the alarm weekly. How can I do this using android_alarm_manager or any other such method?

Comment: try AlarmClock instead

Comment: @KKKKK Is it [this](https://pub.dev/packages/alarmclock) library?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock

Comment: Alarm Clock is usually used to set the clock time application in your device from your apk

Comment: I saw now the flutter tag, idk if alarmClock is available with flutter

Comment: @KKKKK There is a library called AlarmClock for flutter, but there is no proper documentation or a example. Anyway thank you. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can repeat that process for every day the user selects. Keep the _id you assign for each of the 7 days, so you can cancel specific days when the user disables them.

By the way, `DateTime` has [a weekday property](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-core/DateTime/weekday.html) that indicates what day of the week it represents. So to find the next Monday for example, you can add a day to `DateTime.now()` until its `weekday == 1`.